# How to set image on colorchooser in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i have made color chooser in jQuery and i want to set an image on color  chooser button.

```
code: 

< body>
<input type="color" class="back-color-change"/>
</body>
<script>
$(".back-color-change").on("change",function(){
var colorpick=($(".back-color-change").val());
$(".body").css("background-color",colorpick);
 });
</script>
```

[i want this type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vohn.png) 
[instead of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Ugt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the input-element an opacity of zero and surround it with an element containing your image as Background-Image. See the example in the snippet:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
.colorpicker-img {
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vohn.png');
width: 6em;
height:4em;
}
.colorpicker-img input[type="color"] {
opacity:0;
width: 6em;
height:4em;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="colorpicker-img">
    <input type="color" class="back-color-change" />
</div>
</body>

<script>
    $(".back-color-change").on("change", function () {
        var colorpick = this.value;
        $("body").css("background-color", colorpick);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx boundle of thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label` for color picker. Hide color picker and use `label` `for` like following.

```js
$(".back-color-change").on("change", function () {
    var colorpick = this.value;
    $("body").css("background-color", colorpick);
});
```

```css
#color {
    display: none;
}
#color + label {
    background-image: url('http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/color-picker.png');
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 75px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="color" class="back-color-change" id="color" />
<label for="color"></label>
```

Comment: no dear it just show the button and i want to override the image on button of color chooser. when i click on image then the color chooser should call

Comment: i want to click the image to call the color chooser instead of clicking on color chooser button. may be now you will understand what i mean.